# How to translate this esbuild CLI sentence to JS file

Tags: javascript, typescript, esbuild

I managed to construct this `esbuild` CLI sentence, but I am struggling to transform it to a JS build file:

```sh
esbuild out1=src/out1.ts out2=src/out2.ts out3=src/out3.ts --bundle --outdir=dist --watch --minify
```

This takes 3 different files and bundles it to 3 different files, that is exactly what I want. But now I want to add more bundle rules, and I don't want to keeping adding to this and have a separate file for the bundle.

Someone can point me to the docs or giving some hints on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the silliest thing. Just add them as an `entryPoints` and add the left ones to the [`esbuild.build`](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#build-api) config:

```js
import { build } from 'esbuild';

build({
  entryPoints: ['src/out1.ts', "src/out2.ts", "src/out3.ts"],
  outdir: 'dist',
  minify: true,
  bundle: true,
  watch: true,
  target: 'es2020',
}).catch(error => process.exit(1));
```